# JQuery can't find my div element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2005, modal-dialog

I have jquery function in my script file:

```
function modalpopup(id) 
    {
        var searchid = "\"#" + id + "\"";
        var element = $(searchid );
        element.dialog({
            height: 340,
            width: 500,
            modal: true
        });

    }
```

in my asp.net 2.0 file I have the following:

```
<a id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_HyperLinkInfo"  onclick="modalpopup('_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_details10')">
    <img src="../Images/info_icon.PNG" border="0" /></a>

<div id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_details10" title="Dialog Title"
    style="display: none;">
    <center>
        <table class="table_class" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" rules="all" border="1"
            id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder" style="border-style: None; height: 24px; width: 800px;
            font-size: 16px;">
            <tr class="table_header_class" style="color: DarkGray; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;
                white-space: nowrap">
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    customer details </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

Its look like its a simple jquery job to find the div element but the jquery result is null!!

What I'm doing wrong here?
There is no error format in my html code

Please help

Comment: Why the extra quotes? `var searchid = "\"#" + id + "\"";` You're searching for something named `"#id_name"` instead of searching for just `#id_name`

Comment: the answer below and in the comment will work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function modalpopup(id) 
    {
     alert(id);
        var searchid = id;
        var element = $("#"+searchid );
        element.dialog({
            height: 340,
            width: 500,
            modal: true
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_HyperLinkInfo"  onclick="modalpopup('_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_details10');">
   <img src="../Images/info_icon.PNG" border="0" /></a>

<div id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder_DataGrid1__ctl2_details10" title="Dialog Title"
    style="display: none;">
    <center>
        <table class="table_class" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" rules="all" border="1"
            id="_ctl0_MainContentPlaceHolder" style="border-style: None; height: 24px; width: 800px;
            font-size: 16px;">
            <tr class="table_header_class" style="color: DarkGray; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;
                white-space: nowrap">
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    customer details </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Well this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/eorozco/SbGQa/

Comment: I gess this is a deep jquery problem. 
I did try all suggested here but still my element is null.

Is it posible that my jquery link is not right? In my master page you can see this 3 line:

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>



Any other idea?

Comment: Also i added an href="javascript:void(0);" to the "a" tag, this is a good practice.

Comment: I'm using Asp.net 2.0

Comment: The server side language doestn matter, the rendered javascript and html are the problem.

Comment: I change mainly 3 things as you can see: 1. the "a" tag. 2. the javascript function, the definition of this function must go before the "a" tag in order to load correctly. 3. the "http://" thing in te src tags

Comment: I understand that it should worked BUT it's still give me a null. It still can't find my div element. I'm doing exactly what you told me but nothing.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
function modalpopup(id) {
    var element = $('#'+id);
    element.dialog({
        height: 340,
        width: 500,
        modal: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function modalpopup(id) 
    {

        $("#"+id).dialog({
            height: 340,
            width: 500,
            modal: true
        });

    }
```

Comment: I gess this is a deep problem. I did try all suggested but still my element is null.